# PhoneGap Facebook plugin connect with Android

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, plugins

I have a problem using the [Facebook Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Facebook_Connect) plugin with [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap).

I have added this line to file `plugins.xml`:

```
<plugin name="com.phonegap.facebook.Connect" value="com.phonegap.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />
```

And this *include* on in file `FbDialog.java`:

```
import com.phonegap.helloworld.R;
```

I have these files on `src`:

```
com
   /facebook/android/
                     AsyncFacebookRunner.java
                     DialogError.java
                     Facebook.java
                     FacebookError.java
                     FbDialog.java
                     Util.java
   /phonegap/
             facebook/ConnectPlugin.java
             helloworld/HelloPhoneGapActivity.java
```

The ressources files close and the icon is copied. In HTML, I include some JavaScript code:

```
cordova-1.6.1.js
cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js
facebook_js_sdk.js
```

I use the default HTML example with my appId.

When I run application on my Android phone, a dialog says:

> Cordova Facebook connect plugin fail on init!

and

> Cordova Facebook connect plugin fail on auth.status!

If I click the login bouton, the dialog says:

> Cordova Facebook connect plugin fail on login!Class not found

And the [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) console log is:

[image]

I tried to install this with the officiel [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) readme and the 
tutorial *[Add Facebook login to PhoneGap/Cordova Android app Easiest way](http://marguspala.com/add-facebook-login-to-phonegap-android-app-easiest-way/comment-page-1/#comment-156963)*.

When I compile the application, I don't get the error.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the switch to Cordova, everything got renamed. You need the new class location:

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect" value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />
```

You'll have to put your plugin java (back?) to the correct location as well in org/apache/cordova/facebook/ .

Unfortunately, the error for this is pretty vague, but you can see it if you know what to look for. You can see in your logs the line with `Message=Class not found` in it. It would be better if this line had the name of the class. This error happens when you call the JS for a plugin, but then the right class name can't be found in the plugins.xml file. This is also why you notice that any call fails the same way.

Comment: I am bothering you on an old answer but I have exactly the same problem. I'm not clear about the solution you have suggested. I have the same line in plugins.xml and I have ConnectPlugin.java in the package org.apache.cordova.facebook. What am I missing? Thanks :)

Comment: Figured it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857958/phonegap-class-not-found-at-file-android-asset-www-cordova-2-0-0-js938
The line needs to be in config.xml. Looks like plugins.xml is useless now

Answer (score 0):

Verify that android studio isn't giving an error like:

`A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.`

If so, then edit androidmanifest. See: [A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47428898/a-valid-facebook-app-id-must-be-set-in-the-androidmanifest-xml)