# phonegap Class not found at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.0.0.js:938

Tags: android, cordova

i try to use [this plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/VideoPlayer)  and followed the instruction given in the readme.md file.

1)here's my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TryMakan Video</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="video.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function playVideo(){
            window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("http://www.trymakan.my/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/NASI-AYAM-BEREMPAH-KAJANG.mp4");
        }
 </script>
</head> <body>
<a href="#" onClick="playVideo();">play</a>
</body></html>
```

2) here's my plugins.xml which is located in xml folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plugins>
    <plugin name="VideoPlayer" value="com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer"/>
</plugins>
```

3) i've also copied the VideoPlayer.java into this folder src\com\phonegap\plugins\video

4) additionally, some said I also need to add the plugin into AndroidManifest.xml file, so this is a snippet of it

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

but still, when I click on 'play', log cat will return this error

```
08-08 04:54:15.823: I/Web Console(309): Error: Status=2 Message=Class not found at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.0.0.js:938
```

update1: here's where the VideoPlayer.java is located

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Dk7.png)

I don't see the VideoPlayer.java under Gen folder, does that means it's not compiled? Could this be the problem? If yes, how to solve it?

update2: I checked bin folder, and there VideoPlayer.class under bin\classes\com\phonegap\plugins\video so the VideoPlayer.java is actually compiled

Comment: where your `cordova-2.0.0.js` file is located ?

Comment: @ZiedJaballah it's in the same folder as index.html, which is assets\www

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the problem is your plugins.xml.

> it appears in one of the recent PhoneGap release, the plugins.xml has been removed and you have to add the line in res/xml/config.xml instead.

so try adding the tag `<plugin name="VideoPlayer" value="com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer"/>`

to res/xml/config.xml not to plugins.xml

Comment: sorry I don't get what u meant by that. as u can see above, i've already add the exact line u posted in my plugins.xml file. and from my download at phonegap site, I only get config.xml with it, and not plugins.xml

Comment: thanks Zied... gosh the video.js author should have updated their documentation on this

Answer (score 6):

If the error shown in the log is

> Class not found at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.0.0.js:938

The best way is to check **which** class is causing the error.
For those who still get this error message, try the following trick.

1. Open cordova-2.0.0.js in an editor.
2. Replace code on Line 938 i.e.

   > console.log("Error: Status="+v.status+" Message="+v.message);

   with

   > console.log("Error: Status="+v.status+" Message="+v.message+" service="+service+" action="+action);
3. Run the app again and check the console for the above error. You can see the plugin which causes the error in **service=XYZ** where XYZ is the plugin name.
4. Check if the  section in your config.xml file has any entry for the XYZ plugin.
5. Add the XYZ plugin if not found.

Comment: I did what you suggested. I am just starting phonegap and I'm stuck at trying to get a HelloWorld Plugin to work. I get the same error with my HelloWorld plugin. The config.xml file has the plugin entry. I cant figure out the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this error because of a missing plugin. I Added

```
<plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
```

to the config.xml file and it fixed it.