# videoPlayer plugin not working on cordova 2.7.0 - Android

Tags: cordova, video-player

I can't seem to get the video player working for Android on Cordova 2.7.0. I've attempted to use the videoPlayer plugin at https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer.

I've spent several hours trying to get a "hello World" type video playback to work and I'm having issues with paths. I've followed the directions from the readme, but still getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'videoPlayer' of undefined". I am also getting errors in the src->com->phonegap->plugins->video location of the Java file. I've tried multiple locations of the VideoPlayer.java file, but all give me errors. I have included the line in the XML file and the video.js file is in my www root.

[Screenshot](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kvILYakcBc0/Uay7dd7tx9I/AAAAAAAAAFU/NKnTf9psHvs/w1341-h566-no/Screenshot.png) of structure:

Video "hello world" example I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=yes" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>PhoneGap</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="video.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init(){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", devRdy, true);
}

function devRdy() {
console.log("**************");
console.log("**************");
console.log("**************");
console.log("the device is ready");
console.log("**************");
console.log("**************");
console.log("**************");
}

function playVideo(vidUrl) {
window.plugins.videoPlayer.play(vidUrl);
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="init();">
<a href="#" onclick="playVideo('http://www.flabber.nl/sites/flabber.nl/files/PingPongakaTableTennisSD.mp4')">Play HTTP</a><p/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide your project structure in the question. The [link](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kvILYakcBc0/Uay7dd7tx9I/AAAAAAAAAFU/NKnTf9psHvs/w1341-h566-no/Screenshot.png) you provided appear to be dead. This could prove valuable to other people on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with readme, instead of updating plugins.xml you need to update config.xml.

[phonegap Class not found at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.0.0.js:938](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857958/phonegap-class-not-found-at-file-android-asset-www-cordova-2-0-0-js938)