# A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk, react-native-fbsdk

I am trying to setup fbsdk on Android using react native and the fbsdk wrapper https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk. I have it working on iOS but I am stuck on Android. I followed all the steps according the github readme.

MainApplication.java

```
@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">FacebookLogin</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">1343643482425305</string>
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb1343643482425305</string>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

But I am getting this error from LogCat

```
11-22 06:57:13.236 7570-7570/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-22 06:57:13.244 7570-7570/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
11-22 06:57:13.361 7570-7570/com.facebooklogin I/FacebookInitProvider: Failed to auto initialize the Facebook SDK
                                                                       A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.
                                                                           at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:276)
                                                                           at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:232)
                                                                           at com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider.onCreate(FacebookInitProvider.java:20)
                                                                           at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919)
                                                                           at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6285)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5851)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5772)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
11-22 06:57:13.364 7570-7570/com.facebooklogin D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-22 06:57:13.365 7570-7570/com.facebooklogin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.facebooklogin, PID: 7570
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.facebooklogin.MainApplication: A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5794)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                  Caused by: A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.
                                                                     at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:276)
                                                                     at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:232)
                                                                     at com.facebooklogin.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:53)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5791)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below in build.gradle(Module:app) file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

and

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'
```

now add below in AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
 <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
           android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

add following in activity_main.xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.demonuts.fblogin.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/text"/>

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/btnfb"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i already the top 3 sections added from the following the steps. It wasn't working. The last part is not necessary since I am using react native right?

Answer (score 14):

The meta-data in my case were located out of the application scope. Normally, it should be located in your manifest like this:

```
<application>
      ...
      <meta-data
                android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    </application>
```

Comment: I made same mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing:

`<string name="facebook_app_id">1343643482425305</string>`

with

`<string name="facebook_application_id">1343643482425305</string>`

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue when I create a new project in Facebook develop console, and then all configure is right but without install Facebook in test device.

Just install Facebook app!!!! then the error log is dispear.